# C++ ADT proper header files?

Tags: c++

I am making my own ADT, the issue I am having is the program won't compile as it crashes with an error  C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [mainpoly.o] Error -1073741819.
I am not sure what that means, but i think it has to do with how i am naming my files (.h,.cpp). Right now I want to get my program to compile so I can test out the bugs in my ADT, i just need help in getting the program to compile at this point, not the errors in the program itself, thank you. I dont know what extension to give to what file (if thats even the core issue) Also, not sure hot to separate the three programs here on the forums, sorry.

Here are the three files

```
 #ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
 #define POLYNOMIAL_H 

 #include <string>
 #include <vector>

struct v{
   int coe;
   int deg;
   };
class polynomial{
  private:               
          vector<v> poly;
  public:
           ~polynomial();
           polynomial(int, int);
           int degree();
           int coeffecient(int);
           void changeCoeffcient(int, int);
           void mulpoly(int, int);
           int addpoly(int, int);
           int getpoly();
};             
#endif  







#include "polynomial.h"
#include <vector>

polynomial::polynomial(int coeffecient, int degree){
                                coe=coeffecient;
                                deg=degree;
                                v t;                                    
                                t.co=coe;
                                t.de=deg;
                                poly.push_back(t);


                                }
  polynomial::~polynomial(){
                      delete[];
                      }
  int polynomial::degree(){
                     return poly;
                     }
  int polynomial::coeffecient(power){
int i=power;
int val;
for(int z=0;z<t.size;z++){
        if(i=t.de[z]){
             val=t.co[z];        
             break;         
        }
        else{
             return 0;
             }
             }
 return val;
}                       
void polynomial::changeCoeffcient(int newCoeffcient, int power){
int i=power;    
for(int z=0;z<t.size;z++){
        if(i=t.de[z]){
             t.co[z]=newCoeffcient;                         
             break;         
        }
        else{
             return 0;
             }
             }

 }        

 void polynomial::mulpoly(int coeffecient, int mul){
int i=coeffecient;    
for(int z=0;z<t.size;z++){
        if(i=t.co[z]){
             t.co[z]*=mul;                         
             break;         
        }
        else{
             return 0;
             }
             }

 }




 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <polynomial.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main(){
int i;
polynomial poly(3,5);
i=poly.degree();        
cout<<"The value is: "<<i;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
  }
```

Comment: In your `polynomial.h` file, you should prefix `vector` with `std::vector` which doesn't demand the users of the class to declare "using namespace std;" or "using std::vector;"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the line `delete [];`?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: The value -1073741819 translates to 0xC0000005, which is an access failure error code.  Use a debugger and find out which line is causing the error.

Comment: I am using Dec c++; The line delete[]; just a habbit for end constructor

Comment: Also, both files are named .h, while the main file is .cpp, is that correct?

Comment: I cant use the debugger since the program wont compile